# Gallio test suite installation

Tags: .net, testing, installation, mbunit, gallio

I am using MbUnit test framework and Gallio. 
I need to create an installer that install it and run some test on silent mode.
I noticed that Gallio got a quiet installation mode 'GallioInstall.msi /quiet'. 
My problem is how to know when the installation is done? because when i run on command line it installs it on the background and i can continue working.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really got anything to do with Gallio, it's an MSI feature:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024(v=vs.85).aspx

I would assume control doesn't return to the command line until the installation has completed.